# How do you render a paragraph of text in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am recreating a form in SSRS.  There are some sections that allow the user to 
enter a paragraph of text in response to a single question.

When I generate the report, how can I spread the user's answer over multiple lines?  Is there a text-box property that will automatically do this?

(Note that the length of the user's response is variable, so I cannot manually add line-breaks in their response.)

Answer (score 2):

Select the text box.  In the Properties window you can change the values of `CanGrow` and `CanShrink`.  In your case you want `CanGrow=True`.

If you right click on the text box and select Properties from the context menu you get the Text Box Properties window.  On the General Tab you can use the `Allow height to increase` and `Allow height to decrease` check boxes to change the `CanGrow` and `CanShrink` properties